# Show textview of ActivityOne on ActivityTwo without codes

Tags: android

In my ActivityOne, i have a textview01 which generates some value. I would like to show that same generated value of textview01 in ActivityTwo also without writing same codes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: add more detail with explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. generate values means?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the generated value in the intent that starts the second Activity. Get the value by calling `getIntent()` in the SecondActivity and using one of the `get` methods based on the type you passed in.

Comment: Can you please give me an example. I am new to programming. Thank you